# ruby capybara - get xpath at runtime

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

How can we retrieve XPath through code?

Example we have below html code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <label class="strongLabel col-sm-3">Plan Type:</label> 
        <label class="strongLabel col-sm-3">Plan Subtype:</label> 
        <label class="strongLabel col-sm-3">ERISA:</label>
        <label class="strongLabel col-sm-3">TPA Name:</label>
    </div>
```

I wanted to get XPath, some thing like below:

```
table_results = page.find('#Plan Type:')[:xpath]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#path-instance_method

```
page.find('#Plan Type:').path
```

Note -- I just copied your find which is not actually valid for finding anything in the html you posted. If you really wanted to find the xpath to the label with text 'Plan Type:' it would be something like

```
page.find('label', text: 'Plan Type:').path
```

Comment: You made my day ... Thanks a ton